# GRPC bidirectional streaming in c++, handling reconnect after server timed out

Tags: c++, grpc

I would like to use gRPC bidirectional streams from a C++ Application to a Python Server. The initial streams works very good unless the server times out due to network outages. Afterwards the stream cant recover and no new data can be sent nor received.

How to solve this problem? I've read the past hours and people are writing to create a new grpc::ClientContext and then just re-connect.

```cpp
this->m_Stream = this->m_Stub->PrepareAsyncEventStream(&this->m_Context, &this->m_CQ);
this->m_Stream->StartCall(reinterpret_cast<void*>(MyService::Type::CONNECT));
```

but as `this->m_Context` is already initialized, how to re-initialize?

Or is there another approach, which is more compliant?

Thanks